# Is it possible to get the nth element of a Tuple in pine?

Tags: pine-script

Trying to compute a futures curve by dynamically loading the monthly tickers and rotating them, and I'd like something cleaner than chaining a million ternaries.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a function that returns a tuple you can pass in the element you want it to contain.
For example if you wanted to get the open and close values for the nth candle you could do something like this:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 
at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © kaaiii

//@version=4
study("Tuple Script", overlay=true)

barsBack = input(title="bars back", type=input.integer, defval=5, minval=0, 
maxval=200)
x = bar_index

//Create a tuple with the open and close of the nth candle
tuple(i) => [open[i], close[i]]
[openValue, closeValue] = tuple(barsBack)

//Everything below here is to show the values on the chart
txtOpen = tostring(openValue)
txtClose = tostring(closeValue)
var labelOpen = label.new(x[barsBack], openValue, text=txtOpen, 
style=label.style_label_down)
label.set_x(labelOpen, x[barsBack])
label.set_text(labelOpen, txtOpen)
label.set_color(labelOpen, color.green)
label.set_size(labelOpen, size.large)
label.set_y(labelOpen, open +  2 * atr(14))

var labelClose = label.new(x[barsBack], closeValue, text=txtClose, 
style=label.style_label_up)
label.set_x(labelClose, x[barsBack])
label.set_text(labelClose, txtClose)
label.set_color(labelClose, color.red)
label.set_size(labelClose, size.large)
label.set_y(labelClose, close - 2 * atr(14))
```

Comment: I'm aware of that, that is called tuple destructuring in other languages. 

However, that only lets you pick the desired element of the tuple at compile-time, not runtime, and doesn't let you use tuples as a lookup table for example

Comment: I'm not sure pine supports that kind of dynamic behaviour. I previously tried to add dynamic text based on an indicator to an alert notification and was told by the pine team the language didn't support this. My guess is the same applies here.